# C# insertar datos null

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos, oracle, servidor

Me podrias apoyar soy nuevo, estoy migrando datos de oracle a sql server pero el problema es que estoy tratando de insertar datos y todo iba bien, hasta que me tope con lo siguiente: Al momento de insertar los datos hay campos null y no se como corregirlo.

> **Error managerid ahi tengo los campos null. managerid = reader3.GetInt32(2);

Me dice que no hay datos y causa error.**

```
//INSERT DEPARTMENTS
            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS";
            cmd2.Connection = conectar;
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlCommand insert3 = conectarsql.CreateCommand();
            insert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            int departmentid;
            string departmentname;
            int managerid;
            int locationid;
            OracleDataReader reader3 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader3.Read())
            {
                departmentid = reader3.GetInt32(0);
                departmentname = reader3.GetString(1);
                managerid = reader3.GetInt32(2);
                locationid = reader3.GetInt32(3);

                insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES('" + departmentid + "','" + departmentname + "','" + managerid + "'," + locationid + ")";
                insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //FIN INSERT DEPARTMENTS
```

Comment: En este caso no sería necesario ya que los datos que vas a insertar los obtienes tu mismo, pero en realidad, la manera que tienes de insertar registros es poco segura. Te recomiendo que te leas esta información sobre [inyección sql](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas intentando asignarle a un entero un valor NULL, y eso no es posible.
Inténtalo así:

```
managerid = reader3.GetInt32(2) ?? 0;
```

Con esto lo que haces es darle un valor por defecto, en este caso 0, siempre que 'reader3.GetInt32(2)' tenga valor NULL.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, al momento de agregarle el ?? 0; me sale operador ?? no puede aplicar a operadores del tipo int.